# Linq to Entities Object with IQueryable property run all queries simultaneously

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have a List<Obj1> that is created within a WCF Service.  Prop3 is actually implemented as an `IQueryable`, but is an `IEnumerable` because I need to pass the resolved query back across the wire because the context is lost upon returning a value from WCF and therein lies the problem.  I would like to be able to run all the queries in Prop3 at once on the sql server for performance reasons.  At present, I am doing `list.ForEach(o => o.Prop3 = o.Prop3.ToArray())`, but this obviously runs these queries one at a time.  Is there any way to send everything over to sql server to process all at once?

One thing that isn't obvious:

```
builder.CreateObject returns an IQueryable<Obj1>

public IEnumerable<Obj1> CreateListOfObjects(IQueryable<Entity> query)
{
  List<Obj1> list = new List<Obj1>();
  foreach(var builder in Builders)
    list.AddRange(builder.CreateObject(query));
  }

  list.ForEach(o => o.Prop3 = o.Prop3.ToArray());
  return list.ToArray();
}

public class Obj1
{
  public string Prop1 {get;set;}
  public string Prop2 {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Obj2> Prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Please edit rest of question via available tools for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm completely clear what the problem is, but an `IQueryable<T>` **IS** an `IEnumerable<T>`, so from an interface standpoint you should be fine.

This line:

```
list.ForEach(o => o.Prop3 = o.Prop3.ToArray());
```

seems to indicate that your query is lazy-loading  the `Obj2`s and you need to explicitly load the `Obj2`s by calling `ToArray()`.  You may just need to include the `Obj2`s when you load the `Obj1`s using something like:

```
list.AddRange(builder.CreateObject(query.Include("Prop3")));
```

with `Prop3` being the name of the navigation property in your model (typically the entity name pluralized).

**NOTE**

I don't know if that is the best place to call `Include` (probably makes more sense in your object builder) but that's the best place within the code you provided.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it led me to the final solution which was to include all the entities I needed at the point where I was actually querying the entities.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the Contains extension method. See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Use-the-new-LINQ-Contains-extension-method-for-the-SQL-IN-clause.

Comment: Um, no, I'm just trying to execute every IQueryable within list at once so that I can return it.  Basically trying to resolve the IQueryable&lt;Obj1&gt; and all of the Prop3 queries in those objects at the same time.